# Rails: How to associate a model with multiple parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Note model in my app that I'd like to share with several other models. Something like:

```sh
rails g model Note ...
rails g model ModelA ... note:references
rails g model ModelB ... note:references
rails g model ModelC ... note:references
```

So far so good, but I think I'd like to have a way -- from a Note -- to find the "parent" model. Note that the models are different "things" so I don't think I can do this in the Note model:

```
belongs_to :model_symbol_here
```

Since the Note could belong to one of several different models.

Conceptually it seems like I could do something like:

```sh
rails g model Note parent_id:integer parent_type:string ...
```

I think that would work, but I think it would be at the expense of losing the ability to leverage Rails' understanding of the relationships between models.

It seems like this is the sort of problem that would come up often enough that there would be a name for it as well as a "standard" solution. Is there a proper "Rails way" to do this?

Comment: I think what you looking for is a `polymorphic association` (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Check this, Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Knowing the name really helps!

Answer (score 3):

Generate a model father

```
rails g model brand name:string
```

Seed model father

```
Brand.create name: 'Apple'
Brand.create name: 'Samsung'
```

Generate 2 model child

```
rails g model phone name:string brand:references
rails g model home_appliance name:string brand:references
```

Seed childrens

```
apple = Brand.first
Phone.create name: 'Iphone X', brand: apple
Phone.create name: 'Iphone 11', brand: apple
HomeAppliance.create name: 'Apple TV', brand: apple
HomeAppliance.create name: 'Homepod', brand: apple

samsung = Brand.last
Phone.create name: 'Galaxy A30', brand: samsung
Phone.create name: 'Galaxy Tab s6', brand: samsung
HomeAppliance.create name: 'Washing machine', brand: samsung
HomeAppliance.create name: 'Refrigerator', brand: samsung
```

In app/models/brand.rb

```
  has_many :phones
  has_many :home_appliances
```

Father finding son

```
apple.home_appliances
apple.phones
```

Son finding father

```
phone = Phone.last
phone.brand
```

Add a polymorphic example

Add a salesman that can sale a Phone and a HomeAppliance

```
rails g model salesman name:string
```

Relationship between salesman and product (HomeAppliance Phone) is M-M so we need create a third table for that

```
rails g model product_sold salesman:references product_id:integer product_type:string
```

In app/models/product_sold.rb add

```
belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true
```

So

```
will = Salesman.create name: 'Will'
will_first_sale = ProductSold.create salesman: will, product: Phone.first
will_second_sale = ProductSold.create salesman: will, product: HomeAppliance.last
```

To see all that Will sold add in app/models/salesman.rb

```
  has_many :product_sold
```

Now you cant run this

```
products = will.product_sold.map(&:product)
```

In products you have a model Phone and HomeAppliance

[Here](https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails) you found another polymorphic examples

Comment: How can this be extended so that a "child" model can be shared across multiple different types of "parents" - for example, adding a Distributor model to the Phone and HomeAppliance models such that the Distributor can find its products?